# Reusing angular 2 code written in javascript in typescript project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic2

I have written some services for my ionic mobile app (which is in `javascript - ecma6`). Now i need to reuse that code in a web app which is written in `typescript`.

The idea which i had was, compiling `es 6` script to `es 5` and then use it inside typescript but in this approach i will loose angular's dependency injection and other features i guess.

So the question is, how can i reuse code written in `javascript - ecma6` in `typescript`.

Any pointers to the right direction would help.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but code written in valid ecma6 should be valid typescript. Wouldn't just changing the extension to .ts be enough?

Comment: @cdbajorin: not sure about that because typescript supports type hinting which in ecma 6 is achieved by creating a static get method called parameters. something like `static get parameters() {return [[Controller]]; }`